# Admob ads not showing on android emulater

Tags: android, admob

I have added admob codes for showing ads in my app. When i run the app in emulator it opens the splash screen and then the app suddenly exits saying "Unfortunately,Your app has stopped". I don't know why it is showing. It works well before addding the admob codes.I have also added the code. help me with this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"``
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/background2" >


    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/menu1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/menu2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/menu3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/menu4"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc" />

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/menu5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc" />       
     </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
     <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ads:adUnitId="admob id"
      ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
      ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: have you added AdMob to your manifest file?

Comment: @danijoo :Yes I have added Admob in manifest file.Also added the following uses-permission.                                        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: @CBergson The error log shows 2 warnings. Warning1:EGit couldn't detect the installation path.hence EGit can't respect system level. Warning2:The environment variable HOME is not set.

Comment: Please check I'm not sure but it might be the problem. In your xml in the tag for com.google.ads.AdView check this line ads:adUnitId="admob id". Can you pass such a value in this adUnitId. It's admob<space>id. I think you cannot pass a space here.

Comment: Checked it.. but ad is not showing. Does anything to do with layout or padding?

Comment: Post your logcat - without it we are flying blind. It's likely that the Admob libs are not in your classpath. The logs will tell all.

Comment: @William Yeah i added the admob jar file in my project's lib folder.Now working,but still my status is red in admob account. When it will change to green?after publishing the app in market? Thank you all for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

there might be a some problem with adding googleadmobsdk  cross check yourself with this link   visit https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android.

Answer (score 0):

I think that i can find at least one problem in your application, you are missing one impotant field in your admob specification, you must add that line in your layout:

```
ads:adUnitId="yourunitid"
```

In order to obtain yout unit id you must register your app to admob site, here: http://www.admob.com/my_sites/create_site

Another thing that you must consider, is that if you had just inserted the app, the banners usually show only after few hours.

Finally, i suggest you to add that line in your layout:

```
ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
```

With that you are saying to admob to send only "test" banner to your device (this prevent the risk to be banned)

So your adView should be like:

then if it doesn't help add your logcat output.